# Add variable value into string

Tags: string, bash, variables, special-characters

I want to add a variable value to string content quoted with ' ' because of the special characters inside.
For example:

```
a=500
str='#Test
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
boot-root :: \
   $a 10000 1000000000 ext4 \
   $primary{ } $bootable{ } \
   method{ format } format{ } \
   use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
   mountpoint{ / } \
.
'
```

Unfortunately, I can't operate with the value of $a inside the ' '. It's aways returning me $a versus its value=500

Comment: Use `"` rather than `'` for the value of variables to be expanded

Answer (score 1):

You need to leave the "inside" of the single quotes.
Close and re-open the single quotes:

```
a=500
primary=one
bootable=two
str='#Test
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
boot-root :: \
   '"$a"' 10000 1000000000 ext4 \
   '"$primary"'{ } '"$bootable"'{ } \
   method{ format } format{ } \
   use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
   mountpoint{ / } \
.
'
echo "$str"
```

Comment: +1. In other words, the key point is that despite the OP's expectation, this isn't actually a "string". In Bash, `'...'` and `"..."` are just notations for disabling certain special meanings within a specified stretch of source text, analogously to how `\ ` disables a special meaning in the following source character. `'foo'`, `"foo"`, and `'f'o"o"` all just mean `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are:

Interpolate *all `$` variables* (using `"`) — and *escape* any dollar signs that you want to retain:

```
EXPAND_THIS=100
echo "
$EXPAND_THIS
\$DONT_EXPAND_THIS
"
```

Or interpolate *no* `$` variables (using `'`) — and start a new, interpolated, string whenever you *do* want to interpolate a variable:

```
echo '
'$EXPAND_THIS'
$DONT_EXPAND_THIS
'
```

---

Surrounding in quotes the variables that you want interpolated, may provide safety in some situation (though I can't currently think of an example):

```
echo 'blah
blah
'"$EXPAND_THIS"'
$DONT_EXPAND_THIS
'
```